# machines in different data centers not able to pass message using jgroups

Tags: java, cluster-computing, message-passing, jgroups

I have a pool 13 machines but they are in different data centers and hence would be in different networks. I am using jgroups to maintain a consistency of state of the 13 boxes. I use TCP_PING for the initial discovery since they wouldn't connect otherwise. Although this is done. When one of the box sends a message with destination as NULL (multi-cast) the message doesn't reach all the 13 boxes, leading to inconsistency of state between the 13 boxes. I'm guessing its able to reach only those boxes which are in same data center as the source.

Could you please help me out with this. Is there something specific to be done in the config xml file. Further, shouldn't the message passing be independent of where the boxes are located.

Answer (score 0):

Does a cluster of 13 members form at all, or do you start out with 2 separate clusters?
With TCPPING you have to list all members of bith data centers. Alternatively, you could use a dynamic discovery protocol, such as TCPGOSSIP, S3_PING, JDBC_PING etc.
Note that - depending on the requirements of your application - you could use data center relaying [1].

[1] http://www.jgroups.org/manual/index.html#Relay2Advanced

Comment: Further, I don't know how many distinct sites/data centers my boxes are allocated to, I can guess them to be 2-3 but I'm not certain about that, so how do I use the relay configuration as mentioned below (where the sites choosen are LON, NYC, SFO) .. `<RelayConfiguration xmlns="urn:jgroups:relay:1.0">

    <sites>
        <site name="lon" id="0">
            <bridges>
                <bridge config="/home/bela/global.xml" name="global"/>
            </bridges>
        </site>

</RelayConfiguration>`

Comment: Theoretically can I assume each hostname to form a single cluster just containing itself and then all these individual clusters are bridged together. So if I have 13 boxes/hosts each is a single cluster(of one box/itself) and then these 13 are bridged together. Is such a configuration sensible and achievable with jgroups? This way when load on my application increases and new boxes/hosts are added I don't have to worry about jgroups and it can also scale horizontally as new boxes are added?

Comment: hi bela, I have not information about which data center a given host belongs too. I have the hostnames so I paste the hostnames in tag `<TCPPING async_discovery="true" initial_hosts="${jgroups.tcpping.initial_hosts:HOSTNAMES_HERE}" port_range="2"/> ` But note my config doesn't have the `bind_addr` tag, I assume that not adding it will take the default and that is ok.

Comment: Can you post a setup (including sample compilable code and configs) that works on a local box, so I can try it out?